550 mailbox not found route53 and gmail
I am having this weird issue where on this computer with gmail I get '550 5.1.1 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable' when emailing niall@andyanalytics.co.uk but when someone else emails it works fine.
I recently changed the mx records on route 53 and changed them back. Accidental deployment of old code.
My current MX record is:
1 aspmx.l.google.com.
5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.

with a ttl of 60
and my spf is:
"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:amazonses.com ~all"
with a ttl of 3600
Anyone seen this before?
